# Determine the values of a, b for which the systems have (1) exactly one solution, (2) no solutions, (3) infinitely many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

I'll leave two pictures, can someone check if I'm right? (exercise b)
[image: task]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer for no solution is incorrect. Note that you already found out that the system will have a unique solution iff $a\ne4$, regardless of the value of $b$. So the case $b=6,a\ne4$ gives a unique solution and has already been taken care of. You get no solution iff $a=4,b\ne6$.

The others are correct.

Comment: Ahh, yes, I did not mention this. Thanks